# Is there a way to collapse/expand PowerPoint sections

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

All in the title..
Using Presentation.SectionProperties, I can add/delete/rename sections, but I cannot find a way to collapse/expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, thanks for asking.  Took me a bit to figure it out, but here's how:

```
Dim oDW As DocumentWindow
Set oDW = Windows(1)
With oDW
    .ExpandSection 2, False
End With
```

Not a very intuitive use of the PPT object model, is it?

Comment: Thanks! Several things about PPT and Office automation in general is unintuitive and quirky :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to callapse or expand all sections, we can use the command 'ExecuteMso' like following:

```
'//to collapse all   
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SectionCollapseAll")

'//to expand all
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SectionExpandAll")
```